# python scapy sniffer - duplicate pcaktes on loopback interface

Tags: python, linux, scapy, tcpdump, sniffer

I have a problem with python scapy. 
when I try to sniffing on a loopback (lo) interface with python sniff, I get all packets twice.

But a capture on the interface using tcpdump correctly ignores the duplicate entries.

How i can filter duplicate packtes in scapy?

Thanks!

Comment: Please add the source code of how you sniff on loopback interface with python sniff. Add also the version numbers of python and libraries you use.